# HttpClient can fetch data from Graph API, but can not do same using GraphServiceClient

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, frameworks, httpclient

I want to fetch user/device/organization/application data using Graph API.
As I understand there are two methods:

1. HttpClient
2. GraphServiceClient(Nuget MS Graph 5.38)
   I can receive data using API call through Httpclient, but not using GraphServiceClient (.net object). I get error of cancellation task after 1+ minute/
   Also would like to mention , I am using .net framework 4.8.

```
//Http Client Working Example

private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = "";
    string res = await ExampleMethodAsync();
    textBox2.Text = res.ToString();
}
public async Task<string> ExampleMethodAsync()
{
    string _clientId = "***********************************";
    string _tenantId = "***********************************";
    string _clientSecret = "******************************";
    string _authority = "";

    IConfidentialClientApplication app;
    HttpClient _client;
    _authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{_tenantId}";
    app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(_clientId)
        .WithClientSecret(_clientSecret)
        .WithAuthority(new Uri(_authority))
        .Build();

    _client = new HttpClient();

    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
    // Call Graph API
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    //string json = await "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/youremailid@test.com".WithOAuthBearerToken(result.AccessToken).GetStringAsync();
    string json = await "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$count=true".WithOAuthBearerToken(result.AccessToken).GetStringAsync();
    return (json);
}


// GraphServiceClient Not working Example
private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = "";
    string test = await ExampleMethodAsync3();
    textBox2.Text = test.ToString();

}
public async Task<string> ExampleMethodAsync3()
{
    string _clientId = "**********************************";
    string _tenantId = "************************************";
    string _clientSecret = "*********************************";

    // Define the scopes for the Graph API
    string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

    // Create a new ClientSecretCredential instance
    var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(_tenantId, _clientId, _clientSecret);

    var accessToken = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(scopes) { });

    // Create a new GraphServiceClient instance
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes);

    // Now you can use the graphClient instance to make requests to the Graph API
    var user = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync();

    return (user.ToString());

}
```

Comment: With client secret, you can't access /me endpoint. Try var user = await graphClient.Users[{user_id_or_mail}].GetAsync();

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Agree, I posted wrong code snippet. Now , I have corrected the code to  var user = await graphClient.Users["XXXXXXX@XXXXX.com"].GetAsync();
return (user.ToString()); Still I get error - "A task was canceled." and in task - it says status - cancelled, Method = null and Result = "Not yet computed".

Comment: Could you share what error you get when you call graphClient.Users[{user_id_or_mail}].GetAsync(); .

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I have changed my code as below and it's working fine.
public async Task<GraphServiceClient> CreateGraphClientAsync()
 {
     
         HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();


         var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(_tenantId, _clientId, _clientSecret);


         var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(_httpClient, credential);

         return graphClient;
     
     
 }